# How to add a method

Tags: javascript

Define a new object called ‘CityMap’ that can be instantiated with ‘new’, using its constructor. The constructor takes one parameter as a string - this list of cities and their latitudes and longitudes(FE:   "Nashville, TN", 36.17, -86.78; "New York, NY", 40.71, -74.00;). This ‘CityMap’ object should have the following method: !!!! return the name of the northernmost, easternmost, southernmost or westernmost city from the list, as requested by the caller.!!!!

```js
function CityMaps(str) {
  [this.city, this.abbreviation, this.latitude, this.longitude] = str.split(",")
}

function CityMap(str) {
  this.list = [];
  str.split(";").forEach(row => {
    this.list.push(new CityMaps(row));
  });
}

var cityMap = new CityMap("Nashville, TN, 36.17, -86.78;New York, NY, 40.71, -74.00;Atlanta, GA, 33.75, -84.39;Memphis, TN, 35.15, -90.05")
console.log(cityMap.list)
```

I made the definition of the object and its constructor, blunted over the second part of the task, I can’t deal with the method, any ideas?

Comment: Can you please clearly define your problem that you're trying to solve? It looks like you've done what you're asking, but I'm likely not understanding what you're asking.

Comment: Slightly OT, but reading the task, i'd probably start with `const CityMap = Object.create({ constructor: function Penguin(s){ /* ... */ }});`, just to see if the one making the task is willing enough to spend the time debating this.

Comment: Seems like you have the basics down, so you need to add a method like the question asks that finds the locations. So it is a loop over and basic lat/long checks

Comment: The biggest problem you currently have is that your numbers are strings. They have to be numbers (no quotes) for math functions to work.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the method to the `prototype` of your "class" like this:

```
function CityMap(str) {
    this.list = str.split(';').map(x => new CityMaps(x));
}

CityMap.prototype.getNorthMostName = function() {
    // Loop through `this.list` and find the highest item, then return its name.
}
```

If you want to use more modern JavaScript, then you can use the an actual class and give it the methods.

```
class CityMap{
    constructor() {
        ////
    }

    getNorthMostName() {
        ////
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what Adam Harte suggested is very good.

Just to introduce other modern day JavaScript features, you can use the reduce function on a list of items to get a single value in the end. For example, if you wanted to find the northern most point, you can do the following in Adam's **getNorthMostName** method:

```
return this.list.reduce(
    (northMostMap, currentMap) => 
        ({'longitude': Math.max(northMostMap.longitude, currentMap.longitude)}));
```

Likewise, you can do the following to get the southmost point:

```
return this.list.reduce(
    (northMostMap, currentMap) => 
        ({'longitude': Math.min(northMostMap.longitude, currentMap.longitude)}));
```

Comment: All of his lats and longs are currently strings. Can't do math on a string.

Comment: Hm, I just tried the following and it worked:

```
console.log(Math.max("1", "2")) // 2
```